# TomcatStarter error with Beans and RabbitTemplate/ RabbitHealth

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, rabbitmq

I am recieving such a problem, which makes my gradle app unable to start:

```
2018-06-12 14:34:21,995 ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter [localhost-startStop-1] [] [application] Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitConfig' defined in file [C:\dev\workspace\domain\application\build\classes\java\main\pl\net\cmp\domain\application\config\RabbitConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'domain.application-pl.net.cmp.domain.application.config.applicationProperties': Could not bind properties to 'applicationProperties' : prefix=domain.application, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'domain.application' to pl.net.cmp.domain.application.config.applicationProperties
```

My properties seems to be allright (I have made a config file, which maps yaml to java class) 1-1.

I also have:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    log.info("Initializing rabbitTemplate");
    return new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
}
```

I am using the newest version amqp dependency for gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-amqp', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
```

I completely have no idea, where to start with such a problem. Have you meet with something similiar?

edit: I suppose the code I paste is not connected to problem - but I am not sure... I completely dont have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
When you have such a communication, you should

1. Implement spring-rabbit dependency
2. Change your properties files according to RabbitProperties class to establish connection with RabbitMQ
3. Create proper java class to initiate Rabbit Queues and others.